# How to change Id primary key name convention in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

Someone who knows how to change the default name (Id) of the primary key in Entity Framework Core convention? Without `DataAnnotations` or configurations in FluentAPI.

I'm trying to change it by Extension of `EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders`, something like:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
namespace Project.Extensions.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders
{
    public sealed class DefaultConvetionsPrimaryKey : IModelConvention
    {
        public InternalModelBuilder Apply(InternalModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Metadata.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                foreach (var item in entity.GetDeclaredProperties())
                {
                    if(item.Name == "IdTableName") 
                    {
                          //Set primary key
                    }
                }       
            }

            return modelBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible? Other ways are welcome.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: You can't change the **convention**. That is the set of assumptions that the developers make and build the framework with. However, they do allow for **configuration** to alter those (what you want), but they way they allow that is through the use of Attributes (DataAnnotations) or the Fluent API, which you say you don't want to do.

Comment: By the way, we can use EntityTypeBuilder, entity.HasKey(e => e.IdTableName) or the [Key] annotation. Thanks krillgar.

Comment: Yes. Those are the attributes and Fluent API that I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there's not really a global setting for naming conventions. The only way I know of achieving this is to iterate over all entities and update their primary key using the FluentAPI within the `YourDbContext.OnModelCreating()` method

For example:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        foreach (var key in entity.GetKeys())
        {
            key.SetName($"pk_{entity.GetSchema()}_{entity.GetTableName()}");
        }
    }
}
```

This will "override" the default naming convention of `pk_<table>` with `pk_<schema>_<table>`.

Note that this will rename primary keys *and* composite keys. If you want to only change primary keys, you would have to filter the keys accordingly, using:

```
foreach (var key in entity.GetKeys().Where(k => k.IsPrimaryKey()))
{
   //...
}
```